# Eclipse can't find my installed Ruby gems (JRuby)

Tags: java, ruby, eclipse, rubygems

So, I am trying to use my ruby scripts inside my java code with the help of JRuby. But there is a problem, eclipse is not being able to use the gems I have installed. For testing purposes, I've been trying to run a piece of code that requires the "nokogiri" ruby gem, which I have installed. When I try to run the java code, here's what I get:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- nokogiri
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939
    <top> at /home/amng/workspace/scripts/xx/x/getMSPatches:4
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- nokogiri
at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:131)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1307)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1352)
at jobs.Teste.run(Teste.java:17)
at jobs.Teste.main(Teste.java:11)
```

Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- nokogiri
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939)
    at RUBY.(/home/amng/workspace/scripts/myPrecious/MSPatches/getMSPatches:4)

I downloaded the jruby.jar from the website and added to the build path of the project. I also pointed the eclipse to the JRuby binary using the Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK) plugin. What do I have to do to make sure that eclipse can use the gems I have installed?

Edit: My java code:

```
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;
import org.jruby.embed.LocalVariableBehavior;
import org.jruby.embed.PathType;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptingContainer ruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
        Object result = ruby.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE, "/home/amng/workspace/scripts/myPrecious/MSPatches/getMSPatches");
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

The first two lines of my (working) ruby code (getMSPatches) are:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'nokogiri'
```

Comment: Eclipse, seriously? Try to install the nokogiri first and then repeat your action. Also `gem list | grep "nokogiri"`.

Comment: Whats the problem with Eclipse? Its been a while since I developed anything in Java, but back then Eclipse was a great tool. The output to what you asked is:
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2).

Comment: Did you add `require 'nokogiri'` inside your script? Can you add a piece of code where you used it?

Comment: I did yes, I added the java and a piece of the ruby code. I am probably missing something...since I am adding the jruby.jar to the project, is Eclipse (just tried on IntelliJ as well) using the jar for the jruby? If so, how do I fix this? How do I tell the IDE to use the JAR for the files and imports, but use my system installed ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the jruby home directory

```
ScriptingContainer ruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
ruby.setHomeDirectory("/jruby-9.0.5.0");
```

This solved the issue for me.